# How can every continuous function be measurable if topologies can contain an uncountable number of open sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, measurable-functions

If I have a topological space $(Y, \tau)$ with topology $\tau$ which contains an uncountable union of sets in $\tau$, and a measurable space $(X, M)$ with $\sigma-$algebra $M$ can by definition contain only countably many unions of measurable sets, do there exist continuous function $f: X \to Y$ which are not measurable?  Also, how is it possible that I could define a Borel $\sigma-$algebra on $(Y, \tau)$? A particular theorem states "Let $(Y, \tau)$ be a topological space. There exists a smallest $\sigma-$algebra $B$ in $Y$ such that every open set in $Y$ belongs to $B$." and yet here this appears impossible since $\sigma-$algebras contain at most countably many sets. Where's my mistake?

Comment: $\sigma$-algebras can contain an uncountable number of sets. Indeed, [the Borel $\sigma$-algebra contains a continuum of sets](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m103f08/public_html/borel-sets-soln.pdf).

Comment: Is the definition of a $\sigma-$algebra as a countable union of measurable sets and all their complements (and the measurable space itself on which the $\sigma-$algebra is defined) correct? How, then, could there be an uncountable number of measurable sets for a $\sigma-$algebra with this definition?

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ on $X$ is a collection of sets containing $X$ and is closed under complementation and countable unions. Nothing in this definition restricts how many sets there are in $\mathcal F$. For example, the power set of $X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. If $X$ has infinite cardinality, then its power set is uncountable.

Comment: Aha. Thanks for the example. I was confused that an infinite union of countable sets could be uncountable. I understand now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sigma$-algebras can contain much more than just a countable collection of sets - even for a countable basis, the collection of all countable unions and intersections is uncountable. For example, take the basis to be $\mathbb{N}$, then $\mathcal{P}\left(\mathbb{N}\right)\subset\sigma\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$, and  $\left|\mathcal{P}\left(\mathbb{N}\right)\right|=\left|\mathbb{R}\right|$. If your basis is the open sets of a general topological space, the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra can be even bigger, and mostly bigger than the cardinality of the basis.